# whatsapp issues

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I was on WhatsApp for quite some time two years back, and then unistalled it. Suddenly today my friend got a ping that "abhilash left". If Iam using and leave it, the message was understood. If I was using and someone removes me, the message would be "user removed". Please reply as to how it can happen.
(Abhilash)

Comment: Whatever be the case, please don't put your phone number here. This is a public site. We should not be held responsible later for any spam calls/messages to your number.

Comment: Also, I couldn't understand your problem. We're you in a group that you left, which is why that message came up? Moreover, you can easily contact whatsapp authorities for better info.

Comment: I was never in that group. This group was created less than 2 years back and I uninstalled Whats App much earlier to it. How do I contact WhatsApp authorities, s when I wrote to support @whatsapp.com, a message came......google play store is responsible for it which is now not responding in the help forum.

Comment: Go to the feedback section in the app.

Comment: Did you change your number since you left WhatsApp, or do you still use the same number for regular phone calls ect..?

Comment: I installed whatsapp on a single number and never changed it. This was done two years back

Comment: If You were never part of the group in which it said that you left, my only guess would be that your friend saved someone number under your name. Let him search your name in his WhatsApp and see if anything comes up.

Comment: They couldnt find me on whatsapp? So now what to do to confirm how they got "left" message

Comment: It's possible that WhatsApp deletes an account after 2 years of inactivity, Even though i couldn't find any proof for that it's still possible. Now, when you uninstalled WhatsApp you didn't delete the account, so there was still a possibility of you being added to a group. Now that WhatsApp deleted your account it will say in all groups you were in that you left.

Comment: Yes, Iam using same number for calls

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone else is using WhatsApp with the number you had 2 years ago, which is very common.

More than likely the other person using WhatsApp, was added to that group you (your friends probably thought that it’s your number and added it) and the notification occurred becuase the other person left that group.

Now the notification said Abhilash left the group becuase your friend saved your number in his contacts.

Unfortunately you cannot do anything to control this.

that you never part of. with your old number most likely led the group, becuase they identified it as spam, hence them leaving the group caused

Comment: Iam sorry to say Mark, Iam still using this number but no whatsapp on my mobile